# Tip: FAA AIP, AIM, ATC (point sixty five), are back on HTML

Tags: discussion

I previously suggested using a Google search limited to `site:avstop.com/ac` when the HTML pages were taken down, but due to avstop not being up-to-date, I deleted the post. As I learned from @voretaq7, the older HTML pages were taken down to comply with accessibility.

The [2019 update](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/memo_at_pubs_html.pdf) is that they're back, and I've been using them in the answers (up-to-date to find something, and easier to link to than linking the whole PDFs).

- https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aip_html/index.html
- https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/index.html
- https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc_html/